# Order of triangles in mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, mesh

It's my firist time working with meshes. I was following Sebastian Lague's tutorial about procedual planets, but I didn't understand how to make an ocean without a mesh. I think he somehow made it with a post processing shader.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OULxvDLojic&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cONs3T0By4puYy6GM22ko8&index=7&ab_channel=SebastianLague

Anyway, I made a script that generates an ocean mesh with the same resolution as the planet's mesh and covers only the parts where the ocean should exist. Ask question, because I know I didn't explain well. My problem is: **the mesh deosn't appear**. I'm almost certain its because I didn't populate the mesh.triangles array properly . Can someone please explain how to do it properly?

(Maybe i'm generating the ocean in the wrong way. If so, how should I do it?)

Here's the code:

```cs
public OceanFace(Mesh mesh, TerrainFace face, int resolution, float elevation )
    {
        this.mesh = mesh;
        terrainFace = face;
        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.elevation = elevation ;
        decrements = new int[6,2] {
            
            {-resolution - 1, -resolution },
            { -resolution,1} ,
            {1,resolution+1},
            {resolution+1,resolution},
            {resolution,-1},
            {-1,resolution-1}
        };

    }
    public void ConstructMesh()
    {
        List<Vector3> myVerts = new();
        Vector3[] terrainVerts = terrainFace.Mesh.vertices;
        bool notGood = false;
        //Adds one layer of vertecies around to avoid artifacts
        foreach (int oceanVertIndex in terrainFace.bellowZeroVertsIndexes)
        {
            bool logic = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < decrements.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (logic)
                {
                    logic = false;
                    continue;
                }
                for(int j = i==0?0:1; j < decrements.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    int pointToCheck = oceanVertIndex + decrements[i,j];
                
                    logic = !InsideArray(pointToCheck, resolution) 
                        || 
                    (terrainFace.bellowZeroVertsIndexes.Contains(pointToCheck) && pointToCheck < oceanVertIndex );
                    if (logic)
                    {
                        notGood = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (notGood) continue;
                //the order matters
                myVerts.Add(terrainVerts[oceanVertIndex + decrements[i,0]]);
                myVerts.Add(terrainVerts[oceanVertIndex + decrements[i, 1]]);
                myVerts.Add(terrainVerts[oceanVertIndex ]);
                
            }
                
        }
        int vertsCount = myVerts.Count;
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = myVerts.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = From0ToLength(vertsCount);//from 0 to vert.length
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.uv = (mesh.uv.Length == vertsCount) ? mesh.uv : new Vector2[vertsCount];


    }
    int[] From0ToLength(int length)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            arr[i] = i;
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: What tutorial? Where? Link?

Comment: @Exile79 oh shoot. I forgot xD

Comment: I edited the question, but here it is anyways: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OULxvDLojic&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cONs3T0By4puYy6GM22ko8&index=7&ab_channel=SebastianLague